# How do I connect to a Usb port in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, serial-port, usb

I am trying to use a Lidar sensor to obtain distance measurements for a processing algorithm. I want to connect the Lidar to a jupyter notebook and I am trying to make this connection with the manufacturer's code provided below. On my laptop the lidar is attached in the COM4 port, however I am not completely sure if I am trying to connect in the correct way as I keep getting the following error:

> could not open port '/dev/ttyUSB0': FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system
> cannot find the path specified.', None

**The standard code from the manufacturer:**

```
    import serial

    print('Running SF30 sample.')

    # Make a connection to the com port. USB0 is the first default port assigned to USB serial devices.
    serialPortName = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
    serialPortBaudRate = 115200
    port = serial.Serial(serialPortName, serialPortBaudRate, timeout=0.1)

    # Clear buffer of any partial responses.
    port.readline()

    # Continuously gather distance data.
    while True: 
        # Each reading is contained on a single line.
        distanceStr = port.readline()
    
        # Convert the string to a numeric distance value.
        try:
            splitStr = distanceStr.split(" ")
            distance = float(splitStr[0])
        except ValueError:
            # It is possible that the SF30 does not get a valid signal, we represent this case as a -1.0m.
            distance = -1.0     

        # Do what you want with the distance information here.
        print(distance)
```

I tried changing the /dev/ttyUSB0 to just COM4 and got the following error:
could not open port 'COM4': PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied.', None, 5)

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that can be impossible unless you can find a way to forward this USB resource to Jupyter scope.
Jupyter is running in some sandbox environment (usually starts from a specific folder) and doesn't know / has permission to your computer's resources.

You can still run the code outside of Jupyter and store the data in Jupyter folder, and then access it from Jupyter as regular.